# How do i display a dataframe of a categorical variable like 'Purpose'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do i display a dataframe of a categorical variable like 'Purpose' and the total distance travelled for that particular Purpose when i have a 'Miles' column

[image]

Comment: Please have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You should use `pd.DataFrame.groupby` like this:

```py
df.groupby("PURPOSE*")["MILES*"].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

go row-by-row, and collect values into a defaultdict(float).

```
totals_per_purpose=defaultdict(float)
for row in df:
  totals_per_purpose[row[purpose_col]]+=row[total_col]
```

That's your strategy, I'm from mobile, so the actual code may need to be slightly modified.